# Изменить цвет текста в Preference

Tags: android

Есть `xml` файл с разметкой для настроек. Как можно поменять цвет текста в `PreferenceCategory` и `Preference`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="preferenceScreen" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Настройки шрифтов">

        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/title_font_size"
            android:entryValues="@array/title_font_size"
            android:key="title_font_size"
            android:title="Размер заголовка" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="billing"
        android:summary="@string/settings_billing_summary"
        android:title="@string/settings_billing">

        <Preference
            android:key="purchase"
            android:title="Отключить рекламу" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:summary="@string/settings_privacy_summary"
        android:title="@string/settings_privacy">
        <Preference
            android:key="privacy"
            android:title="Политика конфиденциальности" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```